# ASP.NET MVC 3 Log Off

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to render a Log Off buttont IF a user is currently logged.

I want to put the button inside the _Layout.cshtml page.

How do I check if a user is logged in?

Comment: How are you handling authentication/membership?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    @Html.ActionLink("Your text goes here.", "LogOff", "YourControllerName", null, null)
}
```

Comment: Can you please show me how I can call the action which has the LogOff code? The action is called LogOff and it's inside ActionController

Answer (score 1):

```
If you are using Form Authentication , try 

// Inside Controller

public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

// Inside View (Layout Page) Razor Engine

@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){

  @Html.ActionLink("Your text goes here.", "LogOff", "YourControllerName")

}
```